# Rails 4.2: Unable to add search functionality.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to add simple search functionality to my app so anyone can search articles. After adding the code ,it does not display the search results on the index. But the url shows http://localhost:3000/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=hello&commit=Search

index.html.erb

```
<p>This is the articles placeholder</p>

<%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>

<% end %>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %></h2>
  <p>Published at
    <%= article.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= truncate(article.content, length: 200) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

articles controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index

    @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
    @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")

  end

  def new
    @article = current_user.articles.build
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end


  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
  end

  def find_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                articles GET    /articles(.:format)            articles#index
                         POST   /articles(.:format)            articles#create
             new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)        articles#new
            edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)   articles#edit
                 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#show
                         PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#update
                         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#update
                         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#destroy
                    root GET    /                              articles#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwrite the search by then calling `Article.all.order("created_at DESC")` and assigning that to the `@articles` variable

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search])
@articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

So you want

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
```

because your search method will return all if the parameters aren't present anyway.

Comment: Changed it but got error on the index.html.erb  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Articles#index SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (name LIKE '%java%')  ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: Do you have `name` attribute on `Article` model? As far as I see you have `title` and `content`

Comment: @Neil as Oleg points out, that error would be due to your search method.  Change `name` to `title` in there